# When to use NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA and CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA?

Tags: angular, angular8

When we have to use NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA and  CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in Angular?

What do they mean? Is it config for CSS styles?

Comment: Not too hard to find with a quick search: https://angular.io/guide/testing#no_errors_schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://angular.io/api/core/NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
=> Defines a schema that allows any property on any element.

And https://angular.io/api/core/CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA =>
Defines a schema that allows an NgModule to contain the following:
Non-Angular elements named with dash case (-).
Element properties named with dash case (-). Dash case is the naming convention for custom elements.

So NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA is less restrictive, but anything unknown in the template is accepted

Answer (score 7):

In your tests, when you define your `TestBed`, you need to import or declare all the dependencies of your component.

*BUT* sometimes, it can be really annoying and long to write it, when your tests aren't on this particular child components.

This is the case where you can use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`. It will ignore all the errors saying that it doesn't know the child component `<some-child>...</some-child>`.
But keep in mind that it's not a good practice to use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`. As an alternative, you can create your own mock of component or use this library [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks) which is very helpful.

`CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` is less permissive .

Comment: To extend this answer. `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` is used not because "it's annoying to write..." but because when you don't want to test nested components you don't need to deal with their dependencies and so forth down the tree.

Comment: Yes and No. If you want to test only part of the component. It can be a dangerous deal to use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` because the error on the part of the component you want to test will be ignored. [This article](https://medium.com/@fivedicephoto/why-you-shouldnt-use-no-errors-schema-in-angular-unit-tests-cdd478c30782) is interesting on the subject.

Comment: The only error that will be ignored is the error that is about "no such element" which is related to undeclared component or custom element. If you want to test some component you do include it in declarations. There is no harm in that. Nobody's gonna think for you

Comment: Also, the good thing to do is read a full page in docs related to Testing. It describes a lot of useful techniques etc. With greater power comes greater responsibility :)

Comment: I agree. As the doc says `The NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA approach is the easier of the two but don't overuse it.`. And the easier is not always the best solution. This is why ng-mocks is very helpfull

Comment: I saw that schema applied to a regular NgModule. I guess that's what it's all about

Comment: This answer seems incomplete - it doesn't elaborate on when to use `CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA` vs not providing `schema` at all...